# Display last value for each user in SQL (fast)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I'm trying to find if the last action for a user in the last 24 hours was in and not out (it's a software for knowing which persons are still in the building in case of emergency). The table has around 2 milion rows, we have around 3000 users.

The only solution I found was the one below, It works but the problem is it takes 15 seconds...

```
SELECT TIME, firstname, lastname, dept
FROM DAY
WHERE event_point_id IN (20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30)
  AND id IN (SELECT MAX(id)
             FROM DAY
             GROUP BY pin)
GROUP BY pin
ORDER BY TIME ASC
```

DAY is a view with the following details

```
SELECT id, pin, event_point_id, time, firstname, lastname, dept
FROM acc_monitor_log
WHERE (((TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(time)) < 1) AND (pin <> '--'))
```

What could be the options to speed up this?

Comment: What's the pin column?

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your `DAY` view is already filtering entries for the last 24 hours and what you want is to get only the most recent row for each user from that view.

If that's right, something straightforward like this should do the trick, and should be quicker than the `IN` in my opinion.

```
SELECT MAX(TIME), pin, firstname, lastname, dept
FROM DAY
WHERE event_point_id IN (20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30)
GROUP BY pin, firstname, lastname, dept
ORDER BY TIME ASC
```

Comment: This query is faster and it was my first try, problem is that it shows the last user that had event point id specified, even though  the last event point id of the user was different. It shows me every enter even though the user got out.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your concept of "event point". I simply borrowed the `IN` clause that you had in your original query. If a user has an event recorded in event point 22 and 24, do you want two rows in your output or just 1 (the most recent) ?

Comment: I want the most recent, and in case the most recent is having the event point described display it, that event point means the user got in and not out

Answer (score 0):

A first suggestion is for reduce the IN clause  using an inner join

```
SELECT TIME,firstname,lastname,dept
  FROM DAY
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT pin, MAX(id) max_id 
    FROM DAY
    GROUP BY pin)
  ) T on t.max_id = DAY.id and t.pin = day.pin
  WHERE event_point_id IN (20,22,24,26,28,30)
  ORDER BY TIME ASC
```

or

```
SELECT TIME,firstname,lastname,dept
  FROM DAY
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT pin, MAX(id) max_id 
    FROM DAY
    GROUP BY pin)
  ) T on t.max_id = DAY.id and t.pin = day.pin
  INNER JOIN (
    select 20 as my_point from dual
    union 
    select 22 from dual
     union 
    select 24 from dual       
    union 
    select 26 from dual
    union 
    select 28 from dual  
    union 
    select 30 from dual      
  ) t2  on t2.my_point  = DAY.event_point
  ORDER BY TIME ASC
```

and be sure you have proper index  .. on    column (pin, id)  and also you could try add  a proper table fo the value 20....30 with index  instead of IN clause or subquery and use a  join on this table

Answer (score 0):

First, I would use a correlated subquery and get rid of the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT d.TIME, d.firstname, d.lastname, d.dept
FROM DAY d
WHERE d.event_point_id IN (20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30) AND
      d.id = (SELECT MAX(d2.id)
              FROM Day d2
              WHERE d2.pin = d.pin
             )
ORDER BY TIME ASC;
```

Then, be sure you have indexes on the underlying table `acc_monitor_log(pin, id)` and `acc_monitor_log(event_point_id, pin, id)`.